# "head team into the lead"

Tags: sentence-structure

I find this sentence a bit strange, the verb "head" should be followed by a ball such as "head the ball", but it's instead followed by a team. So I read it as "Firmino heads Liverpool" or "he heads the ball Liverpool into the lead", it doesn't make any obvious sense.

How do I understand such a construction? I've also often heard commentator say "blast/nod a team in front".

> 45' + 3' GOAAALLLL - MANCHESTER UNITED 1-2 LIVERPOOL - Firmino **heads Liverpool into the lead**.

Comment: It's a bit of a "pun". We wouldn't normally "head" our team into the lead in any other sport - it's only because in the exact cited context it means Firmino "headed in a goal" which put his team into the lead. On another day it might even have been *Firmino **penalty kicks** Liverpool into the lead.*

Comment: Compare [*Oriakhi **dunked** UConn into the lead*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dunked+UConn+into+the+lead%22) - only possible because *that* game is ***basketball***, where you can score by "dunking" a ball into the net.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand this sentence *Firmino penalty kicks Liverpool into the lead*. "Kick Liverpool" doesn't make any sense. What does "kick" mean here? How do you paraphrase it?

Comment: Go and look up "dunk" to see how it applies to basketball, and consider how that works in my previous comment. My first example uses **to penalty kick** as an "ad-hoc" verb in exactly the same way. You really must stop trying to assign "meaning" to each individual word in English constructions you don't understand. The words **penalty** and **kick** in my example aren't really relevant - what matters is the noun phrase **penalty kick** is being turned into an unusual metaphoric verb usage. *Firmino scored from a penalty kick, which put Liverpool in the lead*.

Comment: I have never heard it used as a verb, but thanks for telling me. By the way, what does "in" mean in this sentence? Substitute Takuma Asano squeezed **in** a thumping strike from a tight angle to make it 2-1 to Japan

Comment: You really must stop trying to assign "meaning" to each individual word in English constructions you don't understand. He ***squeezed in a thumping strike*** - he saw a narrow pathway from the ball's current position (which was at a tight angle to the goalmouth) towards the goal, and he kicked the ball hard into the goal mouth from that direction (and scored).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It means "in" has two senses, doesn't it? First, it means towards the goal and second, means into the goal. In the example above, the "in" suggests that the ball goes into the goal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about this sentence? Does "in" means into the goal or towards the goal? Marcus Rashford darts into the area, ***hammers in a first-time shot*** from wide on the right of the area, and Lukasz Fabianski makes a really good one-handed save to turn it away.

Comment: You really must stop trying to assign "meaning" to each individual word in English constructions you don't understand. Note that Asano could have *squeezed **off** a shot at goal* - that usage is more likely with a *literal* shot from a firearm with a trigger, but it does get used metaphorically of shots at goal in football.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just ask about the use of "in" because it's confusing. Do you think it means towards the goal or into the net/goal?

Comment: You really must stop trying to assign "meaning" to each individual word in English constructions you don't understand.  It doesn't "mean" either. Context tells us the ball *didn't* go into the goal, because *...Fabianski makes a really good one-handed save to turn it away*. But if the sentence had continued with *...to make it 2-1 to his team* we'd know it *did* go in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Without "in", is it OK?

Comment: I don't listen to football commentators much, but it's well-known that many of them use "unusual" expressions both deliberately and accidentally (they get excited, the game moves fast, and they don't have time think before they speak, etc.). So I can't say for sure whether any commentator would deliberately omit ***in***, nor do I know whether any regular listeners would *notice* if he did. But what I can say is you shouldn't waste your time trying to learn how football commentators speak, and what they mean. It's often far removed from "normal" conversational English, unsuitable for learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Frankly, I think you are proffering poor advice. Much of this is about hyper-idiomatic English and if someone loves football, I think they can profit from it.  You have to see it: https://twitter.com/my_supersoccer/status/1392934966107860994 It means: Firmino does a HEAD SHOT which puts Liverpool "in the lead". The commentator has combined the verb head with "in the lead". And has made Liverpool the direct object. It's as elegant as the shot.

Comment: @Lambie: "as elegant as the shot"? I know they call it "the beautiful game". But in all honesty, your suggestion that *learners* should look to their high priests (the commentators) for examples of "high quality" English is woefully misplaced! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You know what? When a person **loves** something like a sport, there's no stopping them. So, why should we discourage this OP from liking his sport? **Many** people are drawn to another language through an activity, sport, interest area etc. and also, much of this spontaneous football lingo (a variety of spoken English) is very interesting and creative using all sorts of phrasal verbs etc. This is a prime example of that.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm certainly not trying to discourage the OP from "liking his sport"! I'm just making the screamingly obvious point that it's not a very suitable route for learning a *foreign language*. Firstly because most sports involve a lot of domain-specific usages that are irrelevant / misleading in other contexts, and secondly because rapid-fire ad-hoc delivery from *commentators* will often include "misspoken" elements (some of which *may* eventually become "standard" within their specific domain, but most of which are simply irrelevant / counterproductive errors).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is advanced **enough** in English to take on the challenge. And yes, you have repeated your position many times on this issue. What if someone wanted to learn French wine talk by listening to winemakers or vintners in French. Would a French teacher discourage that?

Comment: @Lambie A lot of verbs used such as this in a football context. Here is  another example: Celtic 1-0 Rangers – Paulo Bernardo **volleys Celtic in front** as he meets a corner kick, and Brendan Rodgers' side lead the Old Firm derby. Usually it's "volley the ball", but it's here a team name as its object in which it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Personally, I would thank me. I have been your only consistent supporter here. And I don't need for you to tell me about verbs in football. Am I slightly annoyed? Yes, I am/

Answer (score 4):

Seems pretty straightforward.

Firmino headed the ball, scored a goal, and as a result Liverpool have taken the lead.

There's no mystery here. No strange construction. It is Subject-Verb-Object-Prepositional phrase. How else could you understand it?

What role does the subject (Firmino) have?  What role does the object (Liverpool) have.  What is the verb, what is the action?  What role does the prepositional phrase "into the lead" play?

Comment: For me it sounds strange. It should be "the ball" as the object, not a team name such as *fire a shot*, *hammer a shot*, etc. If the object is a team name, it would mean "kick a team really hard. I expect to see *Firmino heads the ball into the goal to give Liverpool into the lead*. This would be clear.

Comment: There ***is*** a "strange construction"!  See my comment under question.

Comment: Your confusion is that the object's role isn't the direct receipant of the heading.  This is a normal football idiom.  It's not strange, and you;ll just have to get used to it.

Comment: Yes, Firmino headed Liverpool means he did a head shot which pushed Liverpool into the lead.

Answer (score -1):

As you can imagine, spoken English (and, indeed, any spoken language) tends to follow its rules of grammar much less than written English.

In this instance we have colloquial use of the verb, "To head," meaning "to lead" or "to direct."  More formal uses of the word "head" in similar contexts would be "the politician is ahead in the polls" (meaning the politician has taken the lead compared to the popularity of the competition) and "the applicant was chosen to head the new department" (meaning the applicant was chosen to be the department's director or leader).

The speaker may have picked "head" to avoid the undesirable alliterative (repeated) use of the word "lead," which in your original context means "has the greater score." In other words, it would have sounded worse to say...

> Firmino leads Liverpool into the lead

Comment: I'm wondering how "would" works in your sentence? More formal uses of the word "head" in similar contexts **would be** "the politician is ahead in the polls"

Comment: @Nyambek My apologies. It would have made more sense to say "... in similar contexts ***are*** ...." It's not grammatically wrong to say "would be." The phrase makes the use of the two examples conditional and sometime in the future - which is always true. It's a quirk of my personal use of English.

Comment: I have also heard a commentator use other verbs such as *blast*, *nod*, *fire*, etc. Rooney nods Man United in front or Rooney blasts Man Utd in front. "Blast" means to kick the ball hard. So, *blast Man Utd in front* would mean to kick the ball hard Man Utd in front. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Nyambek "Blast" doesn't actually mean "kick the ball hard." What it really means is "a sudden surge of energy or motion." However, without a specific example sentence, this one is more difficult to explain. If used as an adjective for a player, it would describe a player whose purpose is power rather than finesse. The U.S. version of "blast man" would be the basketball term "power forward," describing a player in the Forward position whose talent is forcing a play rather than finessing a play. If "blast" is used similar to your original example, then it's used as a shortened form of ...

Comment: ... the phrase "blast ahead" suggesting a sudden increase in the score or a sudden burst of speed on the field. Finally, the word "nod." I need to defer to one of my British counterparts to help you understand the use of the word "nod" in a sporting context. Americans and the British use the word "nod" differently when outside a use like "to nod one's head."

Comment: That makes sense. What about "fire?" Harry Kane double fires England into the final. I understand "fire" to mean to kick the ball with a lot of force. So I paraphrase the sentence as "Harry Kane double kick England with a lot of force into the final". This sounds awkward. What do you think?

Comment: @Nyambek "Fire" in this context is a synonym for "blast." The verb "to fire" can have different meanings. For one, "to fire the kiln" or "to fire pottery" meaning to expose clay to heat to harden it. But in the case of sports, the definition comes from the military version "to fire a gun" meaning to discharge a projectile with force. Thus, "double fires England" is a light-heated and energetic way of saying Kane kicked two balls into the goal net with force, energy, and excitement. Sport announcing is filled with colorful language like this.

Comment: I up voted James' answer and it shows a weakness when Americans try to answer questions about soccer (football). "Heads Liverpool into the lead" could mean the ball was head-butted (bounced off the player's head) into the goal, increasing the score to one over the competition. Our version of Football has more in common with Rugby than Soccer. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150197/discussion-between-nyambek-and-jbh).